# C# process JSON from ipdata.co

Tags: c#, json, geoip

Being somewhat new to C#, I am hoping someone can help me understand what I need to do.

The following sample is the recommended C# code from the ipdata.co's document website.

```
using RestSharp; (at the top of the file)

var client = new RestClient("https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=test");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

My api key works. I can do manual queries and get a response back. Now I am trying to parse the JSON data from the variable called "response" in the sample code above and this is where I get lost.

1. I am pulling the IP and Domain names from a CSV file
2. Submit to ipdata.co and get the JSON file in return
3. the sample code is from the ipdata.co website. Other than what it shows, I am unsure how to process the data that was returned in JSON format and pull specific elements of my choosing out and then write the results to disk.

Google searching got me more confused so I am hoping to get help here.

I have CSV files with IP and Domain Names. I will be querying in bulk to get the lat/long and a number of other variables. The results I want to parse and save to disk. And that is where I get lost and would love to have someone not just do the code for but help understand why I need to do what is being suggested.

Here is the JSON file that gets returned when using Google's 8.8.8.8 address.

```
{
"ip": "8.8.8.8",
"is_eu": false,
"city": null,
"region": null,
"region_code": null,
"country_name": "United States",
"country_code": "US",
"continent_name": "North America",
"continent_code": "NA",
"latitude": 37.751,
"longitude": -97.822,
"postal": null,
"calling_code": "1",
"flag": "https://ipdata.co/flags/us.png",
"emoji_flag": "\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8",
"emoji_unicode": "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8",
"asn": {
    "asn": "AS15169",
    "name": "Google LLC",
    "domain": "google.com",
    "route": "8.8.8.0/24",
    "type": "hosting"
},
"languages": [
    {
        "name": "English",
        "native": "English"
    }
],
"currency": {
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "code": "USD",
    "symbol": "$",
    "native": "$",
    "plural": "US dollars"
},
"time_zone": {
    "name": "America/Chicago",
    "abbr": "CST",
    "offset": "-0600",
    "is_dst": false,
    "current_time": "2020-01-13T21:03:24.060857-06:00"
},
"threat": {
    "is_tor": false,
    "is_proxy": false,
    "is_anonymous": false,
    "is_known_attacker": false,
    "is_known_abuser": true,
    "is_threat": true,
    "is_bogon": false
},
"count": "1"
}
```

If for some reason it is not clear what I am asking, just tell me what I am missing and I will be more than happy to add it.I am enjoying learning C# but at same it is a lot to learn and I keep learning just how much I do not know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you have the JSON from the API and something to do with CSV. You want to save the data from the json, I am assuming, in CSV format. What information from JSON do you want to save? Everything or some of it ?

Comment: 1> I am pulling the IP and Domain names from a CSV file
2> Submit to ipdata.co and get the JSON file in return
3> the sample code is from the ipdata.co website. Other than what it shows, I am usure how to process the data that was returned in JSON format and pull specific elements of my choosing out and then write the results to disk.

I hope that clarifies it. Thank you

Comment: I have been combing google and everything I got back in return left more confused which is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data you are looking for, you will first need to deserialize the response.Content.

When you call the Rest endpoint, you can call it in a few different ways,

```
   var response = client.Execute(request);            // 1
   var response = client.Execute<YourClass>(request); // 2
```

When you use the 1st method, you get a response which contains Status and Content. You want to use the status (200) to confirm the call was successful and then you want to use Content to get the information you need.

If you are using 1st method to call the endpoint, you will need to deserialize the Content.

```
   var obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```

now that you have the obj, you can access any of the data using the square brackets to access the values. From your code, it would be like this,

```
   Console.WriteLine(obj["ip"].ToString());  // Prints 8.8.8.8
   Console.WriteLine(obj["time_zone"]["name"].ToString()); // Prints America/New_York
```

You can access the other data similarly like that.

**Other method**

If you chose to use a class when making the API call (`client.Execute<MyClass>(request)`), then you dont need to deserialize. You will have the response.Data as an object instead that you can use to access the properties from JSON.

```
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.ip); // Prints 8.8.8.8
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.time_zone.name); // Prints America/New_York
```

Hopefully that clears up how to get the data from API calls.

**Side Note**

You can use online sites, such as, json2csharp.com to convert your json into C# Classes that you can use to deserialize your responses.

Answer (score 0):

First THANK YOU 
Some of the code I am still trying from what you posted.

This worked and I could not of done it without your help.

```
using System;
//Add
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Globalization;
using IpData;
using RestSharp;

namespace ipdata_co_v1
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {                   
        var client = new 
RestClient("https://api.ipdata.co/8.8.8.8?api-key=test");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        //IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        //To get the data you are looking for, you will 
first need to deserialize the response.Content.
        //When you call the Rest endpoint, you can call it 
in a few different ways.
        //var response = client.Execute(request);            
 // 1
        var response = client.Execute<IPData>(request); // 2

        //var obj = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        //Console.WriteLine(obj["ip"].Value);  
        Console.WriteLine(response.Data.ip);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Data.latitude);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Data.longitude);

    }
    public class IPData
    {
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country_name { get; set; }
        public string country_code { get; set; }
        public string continent_name { get; set; }
        public string continent_code { get; set; }
        public string latitude { get; set; }
        public string longitude { get; set; }
        public string flag { get; set; }
        public string time_zone { get; set; }
    }
 }

}
```

It worked - 
Once I practice with this more, I would love to ask more questions. Need a couple of days practicing it first.

Comment: Just a note, time_zone is not a string (in your class). Its another object with strings in it. Use json2csharp to see all the classes you would need